# Cannot install rgl package

Tags: r, digital-ocean, rgl, install.packages

I am running RStudio on Digital Ocean. I want to install a package called `rgl`. The goal is to install this package without using sudo code. I also tried installing the dependency package 'magick' but no luck. Anyone try this in the past?

I also cannot download xquartz since this in running on digital ocean. That has been an answer I've been researching in order to solve this.

This is the error:

```
install.packages("rgl", dependencies = TRUE)

Installing package into ‘/home/nick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘magick’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/magick_2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4998781 bytes (4.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgl_0.99.16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3058794 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘magick’ ...
** package ‘magick’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package Magick++ was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Magick++.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'Magick++' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lMagick++-6.Q16
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because Magick++ was not found. Try installing:
 - deb: 'libmagick++-dev' (Debian, Ubuntu)   
 - rpm: 'ImageMagick-c++-devel' (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 - csw: 'imagemagick_dev' (Solaris)
On MacOS it is recommended to use install ImageMagick-6 from homebrew
with extra support for fontconfig and rsvg rendering:
   brew reinstall imagemagick@6 --with-fontconfig --with-librsvg
For older Ubuntu versions Trusty (14.04) and Xenial (16.04) use our PPA:
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:opencpu/imagemagick
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev
 If Magick++ is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a Magick++.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘magick’
* removing ‘/home/nick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/magick’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magick’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking for libpng-config... yes
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/nick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp8fiUj6/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: As noted in the other question, this is not macOS, it's Linux so XQuartz is not the issue. Figure out which OS-type it is and just install the X11 packages for it. Here's an old R mailing list thread that may help get you going in the right direction http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Pkg-rgl-installation-fails-because-of-x11-td871465.html

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this still requires sudo code though - `sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl` . Think this is the only option?

Comment: I usually try to deal with the _first_ error message first. Looks like you do not have the required system package, Magick++, installed. Note the reference to `'libmagick++-dev'`. If this were Linux, I would have expected X11 to already be available.

Comment: HaHa; That comment was made when I was a mac user. I'm now migrating to debian/ubuntu and needed assistance with installing Cairo. Searching on the error message brought up this and I followed my own advice to install Magick++ and problem solved. I only realized I was following my own advice when I tried to upvote my comment and couldn't. I had earlier gotten `fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory`, but after installation of Magick++ ... no rror. Must be "magic".